# Deleting every element can divides another element in the array

Tags: c++

I'm consulting the geniuses at StackOverflow. I've gotten stuck on an algorithm I'm writing to return the least common multiple (LCM) of two or more numbers.

For instance, LCM(3, 4, 6) = 24, LCM(2, 2, 2) = 2, LCM(8, 9) = 72, etc.

Here's the procedure I want to use (unless you have a better idea):

(1) Copy the array into a vector (because we need it to be dynamic for step 3)

(2) Sort the vector (which will make step 3 easier)

(3) Delete every element that is divided into another element (e.g. if you're trying to compute LCM(3, 4, 6), the 3 is redundant because LCM(3, 4, 6) = LCM(4, 6))

(4) Computer the product of every element in the array

Step 3 is where I'm having trouble writing an elegant procedure because all that deleting changes the size of the vector and blah blah.

```
int LCM(int* numsPtr, size) { 
    assert(size > 1);
    std::vector<int> numsVec(numsPtr, numsPtr + size); // need to work with copy of the array
    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
        numsVec[k] = numsPtr[k];
    std::sort(numsVec, numsVec + size);
    // What now????
}
```

By the way, this is part of my attempt at Project Euler [Problem 5](http://projecteuler.net/problem=5)

I already did the brute force way

```
// -------------------- Brute force --------------------
int n = 20;
int k = n;
while (true) { 
// divisors to cross off:   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
    if (   (k % 20 == 0) // 3 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
        && (k % 19 == 0) // 3 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
        && (k % 18 == 0) // 7 8 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
        && (k % 17 == 0) // 7 8 11 12 13 14 15 16
        && (k % 16 == 0) // 7 11 12 13 14 15
        && (k % 15 == 0) // 7 11 12 13 14
        && (k % 14 == 0) // 11 12 13
        && (k % 13 == 0) // 11 12
        && (k % 12 == 0) // 11
        && (k % 11 == 0)    )
        break;
    ++k;
}
std::cout << "The smallest number divisible by 1, 2, ..., " << n << " is " << k << std::endl;
```

and I'm attempting to improve on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This perhaps isn't the most helpful answer, but given the problem of computing the LCM of a sequence of integers, I'd approach the problem rather differently.

From school mathematics, you might remember that

```
GCD(m, n) * LCM(m, n) = m*n
```

So, for two integers, we have a way to calculate the LCM in terms of the greatest common divisor. The GCD is easy to compute using the well known Euclidean algorithm.

So now we have the fundementals of an LCM algorithm for an arbitrary sequence of integers:

1. Let `m` and `n` be the first two elements of the sequence
2. Set `m = m * n/GCD(m, n)`
3. Set `n` as the next element of the sequence and go to 2.
4. Return m

i.e. we compute the LCM of the first pair, then the LCM of that result and the next element of the sequence, and so on.

I have no idea as to whether this is optimal, but it requires no dynamic storage or sorting of elements, so it should be quicker than your solution above.

(Also, as an aside, I'm pretty sure that LCM(3, 4, 6) = 12, not 24 :-) )

**EDIT:** I found the problem interesting enough to hack up a solution, so I may as well share it...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
inline T gcd(T a, T b)
{
    while (b != 0) {
        T t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }    
    return a;
}

template <typename Iter>
inline auto
lcm(Iter start, Iter end)
    -> typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
{
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;

    if (start == end) return 0; // empty sequence

    value_type m{*start};

    while (++start != end) {
        value_type n{*start};
        m = m * n / gcd(m, n);
    }
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{3, 4, 20, 5, 12, 15};
    std::cout << lcm(v.begin(), v.end()) << std::endl; // prints 60
}
```

Comments and corrections welcome of course :-)